# Crear un diccionario a partir de DataFrame, pero algunos keys tienen varios elementos

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, diccionarios

Tengo un DataFrame con la siguiente data:

| Dia | Aula | Horai | Horaf | Cupo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| lunes | a | 7 | 9 | 50 |
| martes | b | 7 | 9 | 10 |
| martes | b | 9 | 11 | 20 |
| martes | a | 13 | 15 | 10 |
| miércoles | c | 10 | 12 | 35 |
| miércoles | b | 9 | 11 | 4 |
| viernes | a | 13 | 16 | 11 |

Quisiera generar un diccionario, pero al usar la instrucción .to_dict() solo toma un valor para los días martes y miércoles. Si no tomo en cuenta el día, sino que tomo como key el aula, entonces solo toma un valor para a, b y c.

Quisiera que se generara algo como:

```
D={'Lunes':[{
       "a": [{
           "Hora": 7,
           "Horaf": 9,
           "Cupo": 50
       }]
   }],
   'Martes':[{
       "b": [{
           "Horai": 7,
           "Horaf": 9,
           "Cupo": 10
           }, {
           "Horai": 9,
           "Horaf": 11,
           "Cupo": 20
       }],
       "a": [{
           "Horai": 13,
           "Horaf": 15,
           "Cupo": 10
       }]
   }]
```

De antemano gracias a quien me pueda ayudar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Respuesta

Primero publico la respuesta y luego comento las lineas del código

```
import io
import pandas as pd

data_string = """\
Dia Aula    Horai   Horaf   Cupo
lunes   a   7   9   50
martes  b   7   9   10
martes  b   9   11  20
martes  a   13  15  10
miércoles   c   10  12  35
miércoles   b   9   11  4
viernes a   13  16  11\
"""

data = io.StringIO(data_string)
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep="\t")

# A partir de aquí se desarrolla la respuesta
D = dict()
type_dict = 'records'
dias = df.Dia.unique()

for dia in dias:
  mask = (df.Dia==dia)
  aulas = df[mask].Aula.unique()
  D[dia] = []

  for aula in aulas:
    mask = (df.Dia==dia) & (df.Aula==aula)
    
    D[dia].append({
      aula : df.loc[mask, df.columns[2:]].to_dict( type_dict )
    })

print(D)
# Salida de acuerdo a lo publicado por el OP
```

### Sobre la respuesta

Para convertir la tabla en un documento, la clave esta en las llaves (columnas) que conformaran dicho documento (diccionario) `Dia` y `Aula`.

`D = {}` en su forma básica contiene como llaves la columna `Dia` y como valor una lista, por ejemplo:

```
D = { "lunes" : [] }
```

Y eso es lo que se hace con el primer bucle `for`, obtenidos los días únicos del dataframe `df`, iterar para armar la estructura anterior `D[dia] = []`.

Asimismo en cada día habrá aulas que están "disponibles" (`mask = (df.Dia==dia)`), en tal sentido el segundo bucle `for` sirve para examinar que horarios están asignados en cada aula en un determinado día, empleandose la siguiente máscara:

```
mask = (df.Dia==dia) & (df.Aula==aula)
```

Con lo anterior, nuestro diccionario debería tener la siguiente forma, por ejemplo:

```
D = { "martes" : [ { "a" : [{...}] }, { "b" : [{...}, {...}] } ] }
```

Donde `{...}` representan los registros de horarios `i`, `f` y `Cupo` ("llaves") con su respectivo "valor" que deben ser agregadas a una `lista` que es el "valor" de la "llave" **aula** `{ "b" : [{...}, {...}] }`

La estructura anterior se puede lograr con el parámetro ['records'](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)

Si tienes un `dataframe` con el método `to_dict('records')` obtienes:

```
      col1  col2
row1     1  0.50
row2     2  0.75

dataframe.to_dict('records')
[{'col1': 1, 'col2': 0.5}, {'col1': 2, 'col2': 0.75}] # 2 registros
```

Por tanto lo que hace este linea:

```
df.loc[mask, df.columns[2:]].to_dict( type_dict )
```

Es filtrar el día y las aulas asociadas a ese día y traer las 3 últimas columnas del `df` para darle la forma requerida con el método `to_dict( type_dict )` (siendo: `type_dict = 'records'`)

```
[{'Horai': 7, 'Horaf': 9, 'Cupo': 50}] # 1 registro
```

Luego con el método `append`, se agrega uno o más registros a cada una de las aulas por día.

### Nota Final

El diccionario `D` emplea la llave `D[dia]` tal como viene del dataframe, se puede crear una variable `t_dia = dia.title()` y replazar `D[t_dia]` para que la primera letra del día, quede en mayúscula para las "llaves"... **no en las máscaras** (`mask`)

Comment: Wow Hubert muchísimas gracias, tu respuesta está de lujo, no solamente por lo óptimo ( porque finalmente lo había resuelto pero con 20 líneas de código más), sino también porque muy amablemente me explicaste cada línea, lo que me ayuda para otras cosas. Me ayudó muchísimo tu apoyo.